# Cronjob should open several urls

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to run a cronjonb to call several urls, which submits (or updates) Wordpress posts each time the page is opened.

```
$sy_json_match_cal=file_get_contents('url');
$sy_match_cal = json_decode($sy_json_match_cal,true);
$sy_match_calendar = $sy_match_cal['data']; 

foreach ($sy_match_calendar as $sy_objects) {

$runscript = file_get_contents('https://www.url.com/single/?match_id=754733&hteam=7020&ateam=3343&season=313&competition=261'); 

}
```

I guess everything works as coded, but there are no submitted posts. Maybe `file_get_contents('urls');` isn't the right way to do so?

This is the submit post section in a target url:

```
    // create new match post    

    $title = $rf_match_id;
    $post = get_page_by_title( $title, 'OBJECT', 'matches' );

    if(NULL===$post){  

    // insert post

    $new_match = array();
    $new_match['post_title']    = $title;
    $new_match['post_content']  = '';
    $new_match['post_type']    = 'matches';
    $new_match['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $new_match['post_author']   = 1;
    $new_match['post_category'] = array(0); 

    $id = wp_insert_post ( $new_match );

    update_post_meta($id,'date',$scr_facts_date);
    update_post_meta($id,'kick_off',$scr_facts_ko_utc);
    update_post_meta($id,'match_id',$rf_match_id);

    wp_update_post( $update_match );

}else{ 

    // update match post

    $id = $post->ID;
    $update_match = array();


    update_post_meta($id,'date',$scr_facts_date);
    update_post_meta($id,'kick_off',$scr_facts_ko_utc);
    update_post_meta($id,'match_id',$rf_match_id);

    wp_update_post( $update_match );

}
```

When I open these "urls" manually, posts are submitted or updated. Any idea why that might not work that way?

Are the parameters problematic?

Thank you very much!

Comment: whats in the url file?

Comment: Could it be a SSL-thing?

Comment: _"I try to run a cronjonb to call several urls, which submits (or updates) Wordpress posts each time the page is opened"_ – why? Even if you get it working, it doesn’t sound like an _efficient_ way to do - yeah, what exactly? What are you trying to _achieve_ here? // Start by implementing some proper error control. Right now, you are just ignoring any error the request might be answered with.

Comment: I try to submit values in a posts custom fields by calling the url. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: I am still trying desperately. Would be nice if someone could help me. Thanks.